# Unable to fetch file from server using php

Tags: php, ftp, ftps

I need to fetch a file from a server (SFTP) using php code and save it in my local machine.
I'm using ftp_ssl_connect() for this.The code is

```
$local_file = '/var/www/filename.csv';
$server_file = '/foldername/filename.csv';
$ftp_connection = ftp_ssl_connect('example.com','port');
$login_result = ftp_login($ftp_connection, 'username', 'password');
if (ftp_get($ftp_connection, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

ftp_close($ftp_connection);
```

But im getting the error as

```
'Fatal error: Call to undefined function ftp_ssl_connect()'
```

So is there any other way to do this otherthan this method ?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your phpinfo() to ensure that both OpenSSL and the ftp module are there.

From the PHP.net page on ftp_ssl_connect()

> Note: Why this function may not exist
>   ftp_ssl_connect() is only available if both the ftp module and the OpenSSL support is built statically into php, this means that on Windows this function will be undefined in the official PHP builds. To make this function available on Windows you must compile your own PHP binaries.

Oh and an alternative method would be to possible use a secure curl call.

http://www.linuxformat.co.uk/wiki/index.php/PHP_-_The_Curl_library

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: I tried ssh2_connect(). But that too is not working.is there any specifications needed for this function ?

Answer (score 0):

FTPS and SFTP aren't the same thing. For SFTP try [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $sftp->get('filename.remote');
?>
```